# "LateInitializationError"

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart, null

I'm having problems with the *"non-nullable"* and these errors when updated to last version.
I have this error message when run the app:

**The following LateError was thrown building Builder:**

**LateInitializationError: Field '_rHelper@616106152' has not been initialized.**

- I'm trying to connect with sqlite, and this is **Helper** class:

  ```
    class RHelper {
  static late Database _database;
  static late RHelper _rHelper;

  RHelper._createInstance();
  factory RHelper() {
    if (_rHelper == null) {
      _rHelper = RHelper._createInstance();
    }
    return _rHelper;
  }
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await initializeDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
    var dir = await getDatabasesPath();
    var path = dir + "Rminder.db";
    var database =
        await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: (db, version) {
      db.execute('''
      create table $tableReminder (
        $colId integer primary key autoincrement,
        $colName text not null,
        $colDetails text,
        $colSave int )
          ''');
    });
    return database;
  }
  ```
- and the **initState** Function:
  I am just try to check if the database had initialized successfully or not!

  void initState() async {

  ```
    super.initState();

    await helper
        .initializeDatabase()
        .then((value) => {print("------------donne?")}); }
  ```

Note: I also tried ".whenComplete()" but it doesn't worked!

Comment: what value is assigned to `helper`?

Comment: RHelper helper = RHelper();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare

```dart
Database? _database;
RHelper? _rHelper;
```

instead of

```dart
static late Database _database;
static late RHelper _rHelper;
```

because these variables may contain `null` values (see your own code):

```dart
if (_rHelper == null) // <-------
```

Keyword `late` is used for **non-nullable variables** which will be initialized later (for example, in `initState` method).

**UPDATE:**

As `_rHelper` is nullable you must use ! (exclamation sign) to resolve nullable value into non-nullable value.

```dart
class RHelper {
  factory RHelper() {
    if (_rHelper == null) {
      _rHelper = RHelper._createInstance();
    }
    return _rHelper!; // <--------------
  }

  RHelper._createInstance();
  
  static RHelper? _rHelper;
}
```

P.S. Please read this article [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).

Comment: I also tried this before I post the question, it is giving me an error so that's why I used "late" key word

Comment: **the message is:** (A value of type 'RHelper?' can't be returned from the constructor 'RHelper' because it has a return type of 'RHelper'.) 
**and the other one is**: (A value of type 'Database?' can't be returned from the function 'database' because it has a return type of 'Future<Database>')

Comment: Yesss, It is worked now, Thanks alot sir!